# django how to save a big model with for loop in views.py?

Tags: django-models

I have a very big model in models.py:

simplified version is:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    item_1 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    item_20 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

in views.py:

```
def form_valid(self, form_class):
     instance = form_class.save(commit=False)

     for i in range(1, 20):
         name = 'item_' + str(i)
         instance.name = i
```

## With this the field name 'item_1' ... to 'item_20' in instance is not recogniced. Instead 'name' is added to instance like other new field...

How can I iterate and save my model?

Any suggestion?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `setattr` in order to loop through the fields and set the values in them. Try this:

```
def form_valid(self, form_class):
    instance = form_class.save(commit=False)

    for i in range(1, 20):
        name = 'item_' + str(i)
        setattr(instance, name, value) # Where value is the data you wanted to save in the field `name`
```

Similary user `getattr()` to get the data by looping through the class instance.